# vector math - find if object is moving towards or away from a point

Tags: c++, vector, vectormath

I'm not too good with vector math, the closest I came to this was:

```
sf::Vector2f dir = findObject->m_position - p_object->m_position;
float d = p_object->m_velocity.x * dir.x + p_object->m_velocity.y * dir.y;
if(d > 0) {
      // moving towards
}
```

where `p_object` is an object moving towards another object, `findObject`

but this probably isn't right.

Comment: You code doesn't make sense: you don't use `dir` but you use `d` before it is initialized.

Comment: whoops, copied it wrong, sorry. fixed

Comment: It looks like you are saying that if the dot product of the velocity vector with the vector between the two object is greater than zero, then you're moving generally toward it.  That is correct, the dot product is positive if the angle between the vectors is greater than zero.  However, I think the sign of dir is wrong, reverse the subtraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dot product.

```
bool isMovingTowards(vec2 testPoint, vec2 objectPosition, vec2 objectVelocty) {
    vec2 toPoint = testPoint - objectPosition; //a vector going from your obect to the point
    return dot(toPoint, objectVelocity) > 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if you know of dot product, but your code is essentially performing the math to do it. Ie, you're code is almost correct, it could just be a little clearer.